# This method does not accept null for this parameter. How can I fix this?

Tags: c#, xna

I always get this error message:

> This method does not accept null for this parameter.
>   Parameter name: texture

`MyTexture` in the `Bullet` class is null, but I don't know how to change that.
Could somebody help me, please?

```
public class Map
{
    Texture2D myEnemy;
    Player Player;
    List<Enemy> enemieslist = new List<Enemy>();    

    float fNextEnemy = 0.0f;
    float fEnemyFreq = 3.0f;
    int fMaxEnemy = 3;

    Vector2 Startposition = new Vector2(200, 200);
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphicsDevice; 

    public Map(GraphicsDeviceManager device) 
    { 
        graphicsDevice = device;
    } 

    public void Load(ContentManager content)
    {
    myEnemy = content.Load<Texture2D>("gegner");
    Player = new Player(graphicsDevice);
    Player.Load(content);
    }

    public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        Player.Update(gameTime);
        float delta = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

         for(int i = enemieslist.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
        {
        // Update Enemy
        Enemy enemy = enemieslist[i];
        enemy.Update(gameTime, this.graphicsDevice, Player.spielershape.Position, delta);
        // Try to remove an enemy
        if (enemy.Remove == true)
        {
            enemieslist.Remove(enemy);
            enemy.Remove = false;
        }
        }

        this.fNextEnemy += delta;
        //New enemy
        if (fMaxEnemy > 0)
        {
        if ((this.fNextEnemy >= fEnemyFreq) && (enemieslist.Count < 3))
        {
            Vector2 enemyDirection = Vector2.Normalize(Player.playershape.Position - Startposition) * 100f;
            enemieslist.Add(new Enemy(Startposition, enemyDirection, Player.playershape.Position));
            fMaxEnemy -= 1;
            fNextEnemy -= fEnemyFreq;
        }
        }        
  }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch batch)
    {
        Player.Draw(batch);
        foreach (Enemy enemies in enemieslist)
        {
            enemies.Draw(batch, myEnemy);
        } 

    }      
}

public class Enemy
{
    List<Bullet> bulletslist = new List<Bullet>();
    Texture2D myBullet;

 private float nextShot = 0;
 private float shotFrequency = 2.0f;  

    Vector2 vPos;
    Vector2 vMove;
    Vector2 vPlayer;
    public bool Remove;
    public bool Shot;

    public Enemy(Vector2 Pos, Vector2 Move, Vector2 Player)
    {
        this.vPos = Pos;
        this.vMove = Move;
        this.vPlayer = Player;
        this.Remove = false;
        this.Shot = false;
    }

    public void Load(ContentManager content)
    {
        myBullet = content.Load<Texture2D>("bullet");
    }

    public void Update(GameTime gameTime, GraphicsDeviceManager graphics, Vector2 PlayerPos, float delta)
    {           
        nextShot += delta;

        for (int i = bulletslist.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            // Update Bullet
            Bullet bullets = bulletslist[i];
            bullets.Update(gameTime, graphics, delta);

            // Try to remove a bullet... Collision, hit, or outside screen.
            if (bullets.Remove == true)
                bulletslist.Remove(bullets);
            bullets.Remove = false;
        }

        if (nextShot >= shotFrequency)
        {
            this.Shot = true;
            nextShot -= shotFrequency;
        }

        // Does the enemy shot?
        if ((Shot == true) && (bulletslist.Count < 1))
        // New bullet
        {
            Vector2 bulletDirection = Vector2.Normalize(PlayerPos - this.vPos) * 200f;
            bulletslist.Add(new Bullet(this.vPos, bulletDirection, PlayerPos));
            Shot = false;
        }

        if (!Remove)
        {
            this.vMove = Vector2.Normalize(PlayerPos - this.vPos) * 100f;
            this.vPos += this.vMove * delta;

            if (this.vPos.X > graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth + 1)
            {
                this.Remove = true;
            }

            else if (this.vPos.X < -20)
            {
                this.Remove = true;
            }

            if (this.vPos.Y > graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight + 1)
            {
                this.Remove = true;
            }

            else if (this.vPos.Y < -20)
            {
                this.Remove = true;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch batch, Texture2D myTexture)
    {
        if (!Remove)
        {
            batch.Draw(myTexture, this.vPos, Color.White);
        }
        foreach (Bullet bullets in bulletslist)
        {
            bullets.Draw(batch, myBullet);
        } 
    }
}

public class Bullet
{
    Vector2 vPos;
    Vector2 vMove;
    Vector2 vPlayer;
    public bool Remove;

    public Bullet(Vector2 Pos, Vector2 Move, Vector2 Player)
    {
        this.Remove = false;
        this.vPos = Pos;
        this.vMove = Move;
        this.vPlayer = Player;
    }


    public void Update(GameTime gameTime, GraphicsDeviceManager graphics, float delta)
    {
            if (!Remove)
            {
                this.vPos += this.vMove * delta;                  

                if (this.vPos.X > graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth +1)
                {
                    this.Remove = true;
                }

                else if (this.vPos.X < -20)
                {
                    this.Remove = true;
                }

                if (this.vPos.Y > graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight +1)
                {
                    this.Remove = true;
                }

                else if (this.vPos.Y < -20)
                {
                    this.Remove = true;
                }
            }         
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, Texture2D myTexture)
    {
        if (!Remove)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(myTexture, this.vPos, Color.White);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: on what line do you get this error ?

Comment: Does the `Load` method in `Enemy` ever get called? And does it load the "bullet" texture correctly?

Comment: That's a huge lot of code with no indiciation that I saw of where the error occurs.  Can you add some detail?  Best guess is that the line `myBullet = content.Load<Texture2D>("bullet"); ` is failing, but without more information it's hard to say why.

Comment: Which method are you talking about? I can't find a `null` in your code.

Comment: Double check that the line @DanPuzey pointed out is pointing to the right place.  If there's any misspelling at all that might explain the null.

Comment: To be coherent, the `Texture2D myBullet;` should be in the `Bullet` class... Then, you won't have to use that parameter for the `Bullet.Draw` method.

Comment: @FrancisP maybe it's because he's trying to have only one reference per texture.

Comment: enemieslist.Load(content); is not working in the Map class, so I can't load the bullet texture. Is it better to move the following line into the Bullet class? myBullet = content.Load<Texture2D>("bullet");

Comment: No, then you would load the same texture again for each bullet. Unless I'm mistaken and ContentManager has some advanced caching. But still, no. Just leave the textures in Map, and IMO completely remove the Draw methods of bullet and enemy.

Answer (score 1):

I'm supposing it is this that is where your error is.  So you need to add a null check and either draw a default texture or don't draw at all.

```
public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, Texture2D myTexture)
{
    if (!Remove)
    {
        if (null == myTexture)
            myTexture = // some default texture, throw an error or skip the draw
        if (null != spriteBatch)
            spriteBatch.Draw(myTexture, this.vPos, Color.White);
    }
}
```

And/or you can put in the Enemy `Load()` method:

```
public void Load(ContentManager content)
{
    myBullet = content.Load<Texture2D>("bullet");
    Debug.Assert(null != myBullet);
}
```

You should use [asserts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kssw4w7z.aspx) whenever you are depending on a value to always be something, ie not null.